# How to use DBMS_DESCRIBE.DESCRIBE_PROCEDURE with system.data.oracleclient?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle10g

I need to use `DBMS_DESCRIBE.DESCRIBE_PROCEDURE` with `system.data.oracleclient`. `DBMS_DESCRIBE.DESCRIBE_PROCEDURE` need `NUMBER_TABLE` and `VARCHAR2_TABLE` types parameters but there are no such types in `OracleType` enum.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are searching for is OracleDbType which has the datatypes you need.

Used in a stored procedure the whole thing will look like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("OBJECT_NAME", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "myValue";
```

If you need more information on using DBMS_DESCRIBE.DESCRIBE_PROCEDURE I'd like to refer you to [this site.](http://icodesnip.com/snippet/csharp/call-oracle-dbms_describedescribe_procedure-code-snippets)

I hope that helps :)

Comment: I can't use `odp.net`, I have to use `ms oracle clietn`

Comment: Well then I'm not entirely sure but can't you just use OracleString and OracleNumber?

Comment: And already found that it should be possible if you look at [this table.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk72thhd.aspx)